# Can't get Speed Value properly - Casting does not work

Tags: android

I am currently attempting to get a person's speed through the use of GooglePlayServices.

I've managed to connect to the Services and get updates on the location, but the problem is on working out the speed for the person in question - that is, I am having trouble dividing the time and distance.

I have posted this previously, and someone suggested that casting long would fix the problem. It was quickly marked duplicate, so I didn't get to continue the discussion, but I wanted to say it did not work.

The below is my current code.

```
    float Distance = OldLocation.distanceTo(location);
    //Getting Difference in seconds
    long TimeDiff = location.getTime()-OldLocation.getTime();
    float SecondDiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeDiff);
    //Finally working out speed (m/s)
    if (SecondDiff == 0) {
        SecondDiff = 1;
    }
    float Speed = ((long)Distance/SecondDiff);
```

Speed keeps on resulting on 0, rather than the proper value. I've cast the long on it, **but it refused.**

I've also tried:

```
float Speed = ((long)Distance/(long)SecondDiff);
```

and

```
float Speed = (long)(Distance/SecondDiff);
```

What could be the source of my problem here?

Comment: float f = ((long)(Distance/SecondDiff)).floatValue();

Comment: can't resolve method floatValue

Comment: but why are you casting from float to long and again it to float

Comment: float Speed = ((long)Distance/(long)SecondDiff);

Comment: To be honest in desperation I confused myself.

Comment: I'm still confused

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get the speed from every location object by the  [getSpeed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()) method, like:

```
float speed = location.getSpeed();
```

Comment: ??? How does that work? O>o Is it the speed from two points? How do you get a speed from a location object?

Comment: Well a location generated by the LocationManager usually consist of other optional information such as speed. You can check if the location has a speed with the hasSpeed() method